# How to obtain android:versionName from Manifest?

Tags: android, manifest

I would like to display the android:versionName from AndroidManifest in my applications Info (About) page. Any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    try {
        PackageInfo pi = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        version = pi.versionName;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        version = "1.0";
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

`android:versionName="@string/verName"`

Get version name in the code as follows

`String version = getResources().getString(R.string.verName);`

Comment: Ah, I see. Define the version in strings.xml and then reference that string in AndroidManifest. I may try that as well. Thanks!